# How to run a cron job without using exec or system function in PHP?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

## **Gist**

I am trying to run a cron job in PHP. But the `exec` and `system` functions didn't work. (Because the server administrator doesn't allow me to use these two functions due to the security reasons) However, I still need to use PHP to run it, because the running time is decided by the formula and it's uncertain. As a result, how can I run the cron job without using `exec` or `system` function in PHP?

## **My thought**

The only way I have come up with is adding the cron job via the cPanel, which is set to “once per minute.” That means setup a cron job for every minute to check the target PHP page whether it has anything to do at that moment.

## **Issue**

There's a possible issue if it always checks the page every minute per day, won't it damage the host? (Maybe it will cause a damage to CPU or maybe occupy the memory space, etc.) If so, how to improve it?

Comment: Good intentions you have there, however I wouldn't bother much with how or how much it will affect the CPU and/or HDDs etc. It's hardware, that's why it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a bash script containing a call to PHP-CLI and then the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php    

    /path/to/my/php/file.php
```

Go to the command line of the server and type "which php". Replace `/usr/bin/php` above with that which is returned. Then you call this bash script in your CRON.

Comment: Pardon me, I can't understand what you mean. By the way, I am renting the virtual host which is not a VPN host. So going to the command line of the server might be the difficult thing.

Comment: Ah. The point is that you can run bash scripts on many hosts. You'll have to check with yours to see if they will allow.

Comment: Merry Christmas *Sam*, I hope you have a great time :] Maybe you get another [viper](http://www.jayblanchard.net/moebius_classic_colonial_viper.html) to build as Christmas present.

Comment: *Merry Christmas to you RR!* @Rizier123

Comment: Usually in Cpanel if you have not closed that possibility, you can know the path of php on the information system that offers Cpanel. Then you can do what you have said. You don't need shell access for make this.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you have a cpanel server, im guessing its a linux box. You run a cronjob from a linux box by typing `crontab -e` and then to run a php script. `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php` to un it every 5 minutes.